# Strange question status after an off-topic closure

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

What happened to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73206/getc-convert-to-syscall-read?

I did a bit of editing, then cast the fifth close vote - I believe I selected "migrate to Stack Overflow" as the four other closers had (but maybe I borked that; or imagined it, it's a bit early here).

The close dialog took a while to process, and now the question is closed as off-topic, and locked by our dear [Community ♦](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

This doesn't *appear* to be normal. If I misread the close box and there were other types of close votes, it should have been closed but not locked. If it was rejected over at SO (which I see no trace of), same thing, it's not supposed to be locked here after the rejection AFAIK.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post was migrated initially, and migrated posts are always locked by Community to prevent the two copies from diverging. However, the asker is question-banned on SO, so the migration was immediately rejected, and the close reason reverted to off-topic, so Community unlocked the post again. The only odd part is why it took three hours to unlock; normally that happens immediately. I'm not sure what would've caused that

Comment: Hadn't thought about the question ban, makes sense for the automatic reject. As for the delay: it took unusually long for the close dialog to close when I cast the vote. Maybe there's something a bit racy in that situation. Thanks for looking into this in any case.